# Google reCaptcha V3 - issue with users from Shared IPs

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question.

I've recently integrated reCaptcha v3 into a website I manage in order to protect the login form.

I get alot of noise from users saying that if they are in the office (and originate from the same IP) or customers who are using shared IPS (office IPs) are failing login.

For the meantime I've disabled reCaptcha by allowing score 0 to login.

My question is.. is there a built in way in reCaptcha to send Google's API information about the request or should I just add the reCaptcha score into my own calculation when allowing the login ?

Thanks !